# Why do i not see my Ajax update on my webpage with refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Why is my webpage not updating itself through Ajax even though I'm using a `form_with` in *ruby on rails*? What am I missing? If you I need to post any more info to help, let me know what please.

### Stack trace

```
 Started GET "/artists/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-28 15:45:54 +0200
 Processing by ArtistsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Artist Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "artists".* FROM "artists" WHERE 
 "artists"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering artists/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Photo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE 
 "photos"."artist_id" = $1  [["artist_id", 1]]
  Song Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE 
 "songs"."artist_id" = $1  [["artist_id", 1]]
  Rendered collection of songs/_song.html.erb [4 times] (3.6ms)
  Rendered songs/_form.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered artists/show.html.erb within layouts/application (60.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 154ms (Views: 133.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

### Code

```
songscontroller:
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:artist_id])
    @song = @artist.songs.create(song_params)
    redirect_to artist_path(@artist)
  end
end

<%= form_with(model: [ @artist, @artist.songs.build ]) do |form| %>
  <p>

    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pague doesnt refresh because get method is processing as JS in your show action and it should be html or `*/*`